# How to block all incoming request from wifi

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to block all wifi connection using iptables in debian but its not working here's what I've tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -j DROP
```

I also tried blocking port 80 as well as 443 but not working
**Update:**

```
 root@raspberrypi:~# iptables -L FORWARD -v
 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 DROP       all  --  wlan0  any     anywhere             anywhere
```

**Update1:**

```
  root@raspberrypi:~# iptables -L -v
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 918 packets, 122K bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source              destination         
0     0 DROP       all  --  wlan0  any     anywhere             anywhere            

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 777 packets, 65072 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**Update2:**

```
 gateway---(wlan0)pi(eth0)----client
```

**Update3:**
my wlan0 is not configured

Comment: What's your specific goal? Just prevent answers on some interface? Why connecting it at all?

Comment: i am trying to make captive portal and stuck on iptables for forwarding all traffic connecting to my wifi network to the portal... m not getting how to implement it logically ....

Comment: You should use FORWARD instead of INPUT.

Comment: iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j DROP NOT WORKING

Comment: @hardikgohil Updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments below your question, what you want is to substitute `INPUT` with `FORWARD`:

`iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j DROP`

`INPUT` filters packets destined TO the machine, but it will still allow packets destined to be forwarded. Therefore, if you want a captive portal, you need to use `FORWARD` to capture packets that would otherwise be routed.

Tip: For captive portals I recommend [ChilliCoova](http://coova.org/CoovaChilli), as it is VERY scalable. While it works very well on small scales, I've been involved with implementing this on an extremely large scale in a nation-spanning network.

**Edit #1:**

You might want to use `-I` instead of `-A` to make sure the `DROP` rule precedes any other rule that would allow it through. Please post the output of `iptables -L FORWARD -v` if this still happens.

**Edit #2:**

I'm inclined to cunclude that your Pi is not acting as a router, seeing as the rule captures no packets (as indicated by the leftmost number). So the obvious question is, where are those packets going? Please post output of `iptables -L -v`. Same as last, but now we want all tables, not just `FORWARD`.

Note: I can see that you default to `ACCEPT`. A common method to make sure nothing sneaks through is to make default to `DROP`, an explicitly only `ACCEPT` things that should be allowed.

**Edit #3:**

The packets seem to recide in the `OUTPUT` chain. Try changing the rule to this: `iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -j DROP` (wlan0 is the output interface, and not the input interface?)

Comment: its not working even replacing FORWARD

Comment: is ChilliCoova open source or is t free for commercial purpose

Comment: @hardikgohil Both

Comment: @hardikgohil Answer edited, see bottom

Comment: its not working i have update output of iptables -L FORWARD -v

Comment: i have update output of iptables -L-v

Comment: @hardikgohil Another update. PS: Please post the layout of how this is connected. gateway---(wlan0)pi(eth0)----client ?